# Are reused glass jars ever fit for storing ground coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, storage

I'm looking for some small container to store small amounts of ground coffee.

I have a lot of jars after some other things, like olives.

Can they ever be fit for storing ground coffee? Is it possible to remove all side odours from them?

If so, how should I clean them before using them for coffee?

The original package is not very tight after opening, so the jar would better prevent the contact with the air...

Comment: If my answer is correct, and there are no further updates I can make, can you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 9):

The Short answer  to this is no. You should not use a glass jar for storing coffee.

**Why?** The base of the answer can be found here: [When Does Coffee Go Off?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/123/when-does-coffee-go-off/166#166)

Coffee goes stale relatively quickly, and the transfer to a glass jar will:

1. Increase the coffee's interaction and exposure to oxygen
2. Increase the coffee's exposure to light, which will cause rancidification of the oils

Furthermore, you should only be purchasing and storing whole bean coffee - as pre-ground coffee is already stale.

Comment: Bean coffee is not an option, because I can't have anything to grind it :( And the problem is, the original package after opening is not very sealed, so the jar would prevent more the contact with the air.

Comment: I suggest a ceramic hand grinder: http://www.amazon.com/Hario-Ceramic-Skerton-Storage-Capacity/dp/B001802PIQ. The original package can be placed in a plastic bag.

Answer (score 6):

My experience is that some jar lids are almost impossible to make completely odorless, while the glass simply needs to be soaked in a mixture of baking soda and vinegar for a few hours. I have even read that leaving the jar in the sun for a few days works efficiently, but since we don't have that much sun in my part of the world i have never tried this before. Depending on the original content of the jar i would very likely replace the lid and clean the jar for re-use.

Apart from that i don't see any problem in storing coffee in jars as long as the coffee has degassed significantly before hand, to avoid exploding lids (extreme case).

Comment: How 'bout a dishwasher run?

Comment: @Ludwik, it really depends on which type of program you use. I have not been able to completely remove the odor in the dishwasher, but then again i have not attempted to use a very long program for the purpose.

Comment: Cool. Never tried it myself, just thought that should remove almost anything. Probably depends on the dishwasher tabs as well.

Comment: Exploding lids are part of the great fun of storing my whole bean coffee in glass jars.  Nothing like a lid that pops three feet into the air with a loud bang as you are trying to wake up in the morning.